# What is your idea about using "practicalize"?

Tags: word-request, formal-language, neologisms

I'm writing a SOP, in the following sentence I have used the word "practicalize" (utilize). in my view, it's an appropriate and beautiful word to use in academic essays, but when I googled it, I found out, that this word is not very common and even it doesn't exist in some dictionaries and also some people interpreted it as a revolting word that should be avoided. What is your idea? what is your suggestion?

> I .... by **practicalizing** my academic knowledge **into** the reality.

Comment: *My* idea is simply ***DON'T!***

Comment: "SOP" usually means "Standard Operating Procedure" in American English.  What do you mean by "SOP"?

Comment: In mundane contexts, there is only one reality, so you should not use the definite article: "into reality".

Comment: @Jasper Statement Of Purpose, something like motivation letter

Comment: @sasan taghadosi SOP also means "Standard Operating Procedure" in British English. Not certain about Australian or Canadian English though. If you're using acronyms you'll want to ensure that other people are using them to mean the same thing - and I mean native speakers of the target language that is.

Comment: "SOP" means "Statement of Purpose" and is a term for the paragraph at the top of your résumé where you describe your value to a potential employer. The original poster should be aware that this isn't a "standard" English abbreviation - résumé-writing is subject to fads that change every few years and the SOP (at least under that name) is a recent fad.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the way it's currently written, it's asking for writing advice. You should focus on the article before "reality", or whether "practicalize" has some nuances that might not fit your context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that by SOP you mean some document setting out your claims to some position (I would guess an academic position). You MUST use plain English in such a document.

The readers almost certainly have very many such documents to read. You will get nowhere unless you make it really easy for them to understand what you are saying. They will not be impressed, to put it mildly, if you try to show off by using words they do not know, and even worse if they are words that you have just invented.

You should aim to use their language and intonation so that like cats they are purring as they read your words. That will not happen if you use the word "practicalizing".

Answer (score 6):

A résumé or cover letter is supposed to be short, clear, and impress the reader.  Taking time and space to define a word is a waste of space in a résumé or cover letter.

A neologism is a newly-defined word.  If the meaning of a neologism is not perfectly clear, you need to define it the first time you use it.

Unfortunately, the meaning of "practicalize" is not perfectly clear.  My first guess was "make practical".  Whereas CowperKettle suggested "put into practice" would be a good paraphrase.  "Make practical" and "put into practice" do not mean the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the others that using unusual or new terms in a resume is a bad idea.  However it's almost as bad to say something like, "to *translate* my academic knowledge into reality" because the people who read these kind of resumes have no interest in pointless justifications.

Instead focus on your accomplishments rather than your intentions, and you'll have a much better time.  For example, describe a *practical* use of your academic curriculum:

> At university my degree was in Intelligent Systems, which I used to create a drone piloting system that allows the drone to maneuver from one geographical location to another, using only GPS, and avoiding all marked obstacles along the way.